# SSRS report in dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, x++

To generate the SSRS report in AX, I need to get the value from two tables to generate the report. When I use the select statement in ax the same value is repeated until the record ends. When I use the `while select` other table value are disappear

Following code is attached below:

```
select DeliveryName, WorkerSalesTaker, WorkerSalesResponsible from salesTable 
     where salesTable.CustInvoiceId == custInvoiceJour.InvoiceId;
select Qty from custInvoiceTrans 
     where custInvoiceTrans.SalesId == custInvoiceJour.SalesId;
```

Comment: guys any one help me.

Comment: In which context is the code used? What version of AX? To be honest the two selects does not make much sense. The `CustInvoiceId` is only set for return orders in a specific context. The select `custInvoiceTrans` have fields missing in the `where` clause. Also it will give more than one record per invoice, which is not accounted for.

Comment: You see the same value by **debugger** or **report output**? if in report output the report layout in lines It has one of these function in beginning `First()` or `Last()`?

Comment: i see same value by Report

Comment: How can i code??Help me

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the values are repeated in the report. I think that is due to the sentence of value found in the body of the report.

In report layout, body, Which of these 3 options do you have?

```
=Fields!YourField.Value
=First(Fields!YourField.Value)
=Last(Fields!YourField.Value)
```

If you have the second or third value delete this value and put the first value.

If this does not work. show me the design of the report please.